# Copying PivotTable Values in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have created a pivot table via macro and want to copy the pivot table as values using VBA. Creating a Pivot Table went well but copying it to another sheet gives me a headache. Here's the code:

```
Sub test()
Dim shtTarget, pvtSht As Worksheet
Dim pc As PivotCache
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim field As PivotField
Dim rngSource As Range

With ActiveWorkbook
    Set rngSource = .Sheets(2).Range("H:I").CurrentRegion
    Set shtTarget = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.count))
    shtTarget.Name = "Temp"
    Set pc = .PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, rngSource, xlPivotTableVersion14)
    Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(shtTarget.Range("A1"), "PivotTable1", , xlPivotTableVersion14)

End With

With shtTarget.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Concatenate")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With

With shtTarget
    .PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField .PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("SCREEN_ENTRY_VALUE"), "Count of SCREEN_ENTRY_VALUE" _
    , xlSum
End With

With ActiveWorkbook
    Set pvtSht = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.count))
    pvtSht.Name = "Sum of Element Entries"

'==========================I'm stuck on this line=================================

    .Sheets(shtTarget).PivotTables("PivotTable1").TableRange1.Copy 
    pvtSht.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With

End Sub
```

The error is a `Type mismatch` error.

Comment: `.Sheets(shtTarget).PivotTables`  --> `shtTarget.PivotTables`

Comment: @A.S.H Still not working :(. Anyways, I've made a work around. Just copied the range values of Pivot :)

Comment: @ramedju  have you tried my code in my answer below? any feedback ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the code below, it's a little "cleaner" , the modifications I made:

- **1)** To copy the Pivot Table's data and paste in another `Worksheet` as values, you need to use `TableRange2` and not `TableRange1`.
- **2)** You already defined and set your `pt` object so nicely to your `PivotTable`, why not continue to use it ? Everywhere in your code you have `shtTarget.PivotTables("PivotTable1")` can be replaced with a short `pt`.

**Code** (tested)

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim shtTarget As Worksheet, pvtSht As Worksheet
Dim pc As PivotCache
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim field As PivotField
Dim rngSource As Range

With ActiveWorkbook
    Set rngSource = .Sheets(2).Range("H:I").CurrentRegion
    Set shtTarget = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
    shtTarget.Name = "Temp"

    Set pc = .PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, rngSource, xlPivotTableVersion14)
    Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(shtTarget.Range("A1"), "PivotTable1", , xlPivotTableVersion14)
End With

With pt.PivotFields("Concatenate")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With

pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields("SCREEN_ENTRY_VALUE"), "Sum of SCREEN_ENTRY_VALUE", xlSum

With ActiveWorkbook
    Set pvtSht = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
    pvtSht.Name = "Sum of Element Entries"

    pt.TableRange2.Copy
    pvtSht.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I am trying you code as well and am getting a Runtime Error 1004 at line "Set pc = .PivotCaches..." Any thoughts on why?

Comment: @LarsHovden try `Set pc = .PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, rngSource.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal))` , and change `ActiveWorkbook` to a fully qualified `Workbook` object

Comment: Are you referring to With ActiveWorkbook to With Workbook?

Comment: @LarsHovden instead of `ActiveWorkbook` use an object like `Dim wb as Workbook`, then set it to the workbook you want to use. and last use `With wb`...

Comment: Now I get a Runtime error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: @LarsHovden open a new post, describe what you need, also post a screen-shot of your data, and then I'll try to see why. I don't want to mess this post for future users

Comment: Here is the new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54755377/copy-pivot-table-value-to-new-sheet-vba