# Copy Pivot table value to new sheet vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy Pivot table values into a new sheet using VBA. I am getting a runtime error 5. Here is my code

```
Sub test()

    Dim shtTarget As Worksheet, pvtSht As Worksheet
    Dim pc As PivotCache
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim field As PivotField
    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    With wb
        Set rngSource = .Sheets(2).Range("A5").CurrentRegion
        Set shtTarget = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))

        Set pc = .PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, rngSource.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal))
Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(shtTarget.Range("A1"), "PivotTable3", , xlPivotTableVersion14)
 End With

With pt.PivotFields("Concatenate")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
End With

pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields("SCREEN_ENTRY_VALUE"), "Sum of SCREEN_ENTRY_VALUE", xlSum

With wb
Set pvtSht = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
pvtSht.Name = "Sum of Element Entries"

    pt.TableRange2.Copy
    pvtSht.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With

End Sub
```

My pivot table is in a range of A5:I266. The code errors out on Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable...

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(shtTarget.Range("A1"), "PivotTable3", , xlPivotTableVersion14)
```

with:

```
Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(shtTarget.Range("A1"), "PivotTable3")
```

Comment: By changing that it errors at With ps.PivotFields ("Concatenate")  Run-time error 1004, but created a new sheet with a new pivot table in it. This is close but I need just the values.

Comment: Either your Pivot-table's name is not `"PivotTable3"` , or you don't have a field "Concatenate"

Comment: Ok I have changed my field name to match and it works. So I added more fields to copy, but when it pastes the data in the new sheet it pastes everything into one column. Is that because of the range in pt?